# WebStorm - How to find source of a problem inside a npm package? (node:36378) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, buffer, webstorm

I started getting this error in the last 6 months, probably because of a update to `node.js`.

> (node:36378) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due
>   to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(),
>   Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.

I've pinpointed the specific package that is causing this warning: https://github.com/irhc/js-logging

It's no longer maintained so I have to dig down and find the source of this problem. However my IDE (`WebStorm`) is not showing any lines of code. I also searched the source code and couldn't find `Buffer()` used anywhere. How can I find the source of this problem?

Btw I'm also using `fs` in the same file, which actually has `Buffer()` inside, but commenting out the dependency and related functions didn't get rid of the warning.

Edit: Thanks to the suggestions by @ix3 I lowered the scope of the problem

- This doesn't happen while running in node server
- This doesn't happen while running mocha test from terminal https://prnt.sc/lh012c
- This does happen when running mocha tests from `Webstorm`: https://prnt.sc/lh01ac

So the problem is in the interaction of Webstorm + Mocha + Node + js-logging. Each of them work perfectly alone, but I get this error when they are together.

Comment: In order for others to be able to help you better, please post more information about your program. Is it a NodeJS program or does it run in a web browser? When do you see the error message you mentioned? What version of NodeJS are you using? Can you share a simple example that reproduces the problem in a github repository or gist? etc.

Comment: The problematic file is the backend side of a web application. Specifically it is a custom wrapper for the logging library. The purpose of the wrapper is to write all logs into into files .log.

Comment: That's a start but unfortunately still isn't enough information to help you further. For example, I can't reproduce the problem simply by running `mkdir tmp; cd tmp; npm init -y; npm install --save js-logging; node -e "require('js-logging').console().debug('Hello, world');"` (it outputs "2018-11-08T10:07:23-0600 <debug> [eval]:1  Hello, world" just fine). Ran on Debian Linux 9.5 with NodeJS 10.13.0

Comment: Just realized I've jumped to a conclusion. The problem doesn't seem to be with node.js or that file. The problem is that file + Webstorm + Chai testing. This warning doesn't show in my terminal when I run the app, but it does show when I'm running tests. But only when I use this file. I'll take a video of it. Thanks for trying to help

Comment: I took 2 videos, showing the problem: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/4s2iyeotno7zmgr/AACuojCj1_9VYunanUFz0tlfa?dl=0

You can see how annoying it could be when I'm testing hundreds of stuff and in between my results, I'm seeing a warning.

Comment: You appear to be a veteran StackOverflow user. Surely you must understand how much more preferable run-able code is to a video :/

Comment: True, but it is difficult to isolate this case, because I have a highly modified rig setup :/ . It might take hours to completely isolate this functionality. Like I said before, I don't get this warning when I print my JL4 logs in the terminal. I only get the warning when I run using the testing framework mocha + JL4 inside Webstorm terminal. I have no problems when I run functions with Buffer() or console.logs(). But I did post my source from videos in the original dropbox link above with possibly needed dependency list.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183326/discussion-between-ix3-and-esqarrouth).

Answer (score 1):

The fact that `js-logging` is no longer maintained makes it a sensible first place to look. However, if it is not calling `new Buffer` (and neither are any of its dependencies) then something else must be triggering that warning message. How did you "pinpoint" the problem to that package?

You might want to try running your program with a debugger (e.g. the one built into Chrome) attached. You can do this by following the instructions [that Paul Irish explains here](https://medium.com/@paul_irish/debugging-node-js-nightlies-with-chrome-devtools-7c4a1b95ae27). Also note that Chrome 70 now [offers `ndb`](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/08/devtools#ndb).

You can also try "grepping" your entire source tree (including `node_modules`) for "new Buffer". There are multiple ways to do this, and they vary by operating system. For example, on a POSIX system like Linux you can usually do something like `grep -drecurse "new Buffer" .` from the root folder of your project to search for all occurrences of that string in all files within that tree.

Finally, it bears repeating that the message you listed is not an *error* but only a *warning*. Consequently, it is not causing any different behavior. In other words, fixing it will only make the message go away; it will not significantly change the behavior of your program. Of course, you should still strive to address it as the warning is telling you that *in a future version of node* the code you have right now will stop working.

**Edit**: Looking at the audio-less videos you shared, it looks like you are doing all kinds of things that your question didn't mention, e.g.

- You are writing in TypeScript (What happens when you use plain JavaScript?)
- You are only running the tests from within the IDE (What happens when you run them from the command line?)

It's quite possible that you are using an old version of `ts-node` which [used the `Buffer` constructor until about May 2018](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/search?q=Buffer&type=Commits).

**Aside:** To track when dependencies change (especially dependencies of dependencies of ....) I strongly recommend using [`yarn`](https://yarnpkg.com/en/) or at least [`package-lock.json`](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package-lock.json) as otherwise it is completely possible that your app will build and work one day and not the next due to changes upstream.

Comment: js-logging doesn't seem to have dependencies anyways