# WebStorm small switch cases without using formatter when hit source code reformat

Tags: intellij-idea, switch-statement, phpstorm, webstorm, code-formatting

```
//@formatter:off
switch(no) {
    case 1: one++; break;
    case 2: two++; break;
    case 3: three++; break;
    case 4: four++; break;
}
//@formatter:on
```

When I remove the formatters and hit Source Code Reformat key I get this:

```
    switch(no) {
        case 1:
            one++;
            break;
        case 2:
            two++;
            break;
        case 3:
            three++;
            break;
        case 4:
            four++;
            break;
    }
```

I tried diving into the preferences part to change how this could be changed but couldn't find anything. Is there a way for me to setup Code Style settings so it accepts small switch cases?

Answer (score 2):

Not currently possible, please vote for [WEB-23817](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-23817) to be notified on any progress with it

Comment: Thanks I also posted the link of this issue in there if needed. Could you take a look at this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53201124/how-to-find-source-of-a-problem-inside-a-npm-package-node36378-dep0005-dep

Comment: please create a support ticket, providing a sample project that can be used to recreate the issue (just a dummy test with your JL4 logging + package.json)